# How can "ask, don't look" be applied in Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

This [Google Testing Blog post](http://googletesting.blogspot.in/2008/08/by-miko-hevery-so-you-decided-to.html) lists some strategies for making code testable.  One item says in part:

> Ask for things, Don't look for things (aka Dependency Injection / Law of Demeter): OK, you got rid of your new operators in you application code. But how do I get a hold of the dependencies. Simple: Just ask for all of the collaborators you need in your constructor.

In other words, do this:

```
Foo(final Bar bar) {
  mBar = bar;
}
```

Not this:

```
Foo() {
  mBar = Bar.getBar(); // or new Bar();
}
```

The reason for this is obvious: it lets you test `Foo` by passing it a mock `Bar`.  Since Android components require no-arg constructors, the equivalent is to pass their arguments via an extras `Bundle`.

**How do you apply this principle in Android when the things the component needs are not `Parcelable` or `Serializable`?**

Comment: One idea I had, might be stupid: `Bar.getBar(parcelableKey)` - then the tests can set up `Bar.putBar(parcelableKey)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I use for that is [Dagger2](http://google.github.io/dagger/), where you only depend on the object graph (or one of its subscoped extended subgraphs) to receive all your dependencies.

Vaguely it works like this,

- Singleton

.

```
@Component(modules={SingletonModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface SingletonComponent {
    Foo foo();
    Bar bar();

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}

@Module
public class SingletonModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Bar bar() {
        return new Bar();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Foo foo(Bar bar) {
        return new Foo(bar);
    }
}

public class CustomApplication extends Application {
    SingletonComponent singletonComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        singletonComponent = DaggerSingletonComponent.builder()
                              .singletonModule(new SingletonModule())
                              .build();
    }

    public SingletonComponent getSingletonComponent() {
        return singletonComponent;
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Inject
    Foo foo;

    @Inject
    Bar bar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveinstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(saveinstanceState);
         ((CustomApplication)getApplicationContext()).getSingletonComponent().inject(this);
         bar.doSomething();
         foo.doSomething();
    }
}
```

- Subscoping

.

```
@Component(modules=SingletonModule.class) 
@Singleton
public interface SingletonComponent {
    Foo foo();
}

@Component(dependencies={SingletonComponent.class}, modules={MainActivityModule.class})
@ActivityScope
public interface MainActivityCompoent extends SingletonComponent {
    Bar bar();

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}

@Module
public class SingletonModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo();
    }
}

@Module
public class MainActivityModule {
    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    public Bar bar(Foo foo) {
        return new Bar(foo);
    }
}

@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ActivityScope {
}

public class CustomApplication extends Application {
    SingletonComponent singletonComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        singletonComponent = DaggerSingletonComponent.builder()
                              .singletonModule(new SingletonModule())
                              .build();
    }

    public SingletonComponent getSingletonComponent() {
        return singletonComponent;
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Inject
    Foo foo;

    @Inject
    Bar bar;

    private MainActivityComponent mainActivityComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveinstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(saveinstanceState);
         mainActivityComponent = DaggerMainActivityComponent.builder()
             .singletonComponent(((CustomApplication)getApplicationContext()).getSingletonComponent())
             .mainActivityModule(new MainActivityModule()) 
             .build();
        mainActivityComponent.inject(this);
        bar.doSomething();
        foo.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by "depend on the object graph."  What I'm getting from your code sample is a God-singleton that uses reflection voodoo to set your dependencies.

Comment: Well, it's not reflection because Dagger2 uses annotation processing to generate the code you'd normally do with reflection. But yes, this example uses a God singleton. You can also slice it up into smaller "extended subscoped components" too, though if you want.